# could not connect to smtp.office365.com

Tags: python, office365

Basically I am trying to send an email from my office 365 business mailbox using a python script But it keeps failing.

Code:

```
try:
    username = "name@business.com" # this is an o365 mailbox bought from godaddy.
    password = "somejunk"
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    mailserver.login(username, password)
    mailserver.sendmail(username, sender_email, 'python email')
    mailserver.quit()
except socket.error as e:
    print("Could not connect to  - is it listening / up?")
except ValueError as e:
    print("Unknown error:", e)
```

Using above script, the code end up at `socket.error` and prints could not connect. I tried to telnet to smtp.office365.com 587 and it connects just fine. I tried many other example to send an o365 email but they kept failing for one or other reason.

After removing try and except I get:

> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [BL0PR02CA0082.namprd02.prod.outlook.com]')

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: On which line do you get the socket error?  Get rid of the try/except and get the traceback.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you tell me how to do the tracerback?

Comment: After you remove the try/except clause, just run it.

Comment: I got :smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [BL0PR02CA0082.namprd02.prod.outlook.com]')

Comment: Well, that gives you a pretty clear indication of your problem.

Comment: Do you still need help with this after reading the error? If yes, please edit the question to clarify. If not, you can [answer your own question](/help/self-answer).